# Is there a way to compare the name of array which json response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I'm doing a AJAX request via jQuery, and the response is an Object which contains one object with attributes and one array which can have many objects in it. This would be a summary of my case:

```
Object
  ->   0: Object
         -> attribute 1
         -> attribute 2
         -> attribute 3
         -> attribute 4
  ->   crebos: Array
         -> 0: Object 1
              -> attribute 1
              -> attribute 2
         -> 1: Object 2
              -> attribute 1
              -> attribute 2
         -> many other objects in the same format ....
```

I need in some way compare the name (or key) of the records of the very first Object (the Object and Array), and if the name equals "crebos" I need to execute another code than when it doesn't.

This is my jQuery:

```
if(data.length != 0){
    $.each(data, function() {
        if(this == "crebos"){
            // code if name equals "crebos"
        }else{
            // another code
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is as simple as this:

```
if(data.length != 0){
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if(key === "crebos"){
            // code if name equals "crebos"
        }else{
            // another code
        }
    });
}
```

[jQuery.each() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)